# How do I get my laptop to recognise the new monitor so it displays correctly with Dell U2410?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have a HP Pavilion Laptop. The monitor is broken. I have plugged in a Dell U2410 monitor with a HDMI plug.

The display is too large I have tried changing the different resolutions but cant get it right. Currently the icons are too large and when a dialogue box appears it is also too big it doesn't fit properly.

I have no experience with IT and have tried to read up on this but nothing is working.

Comment: Have you loaded the proper drivers for the monitor onto your computer? Speaking of which, what OS are you using? That monitor has a max resolution of 1920 x 1200. Make sure your laptop can support that and has the latest graphics card drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Despite not knowing what Operating System you are using on the laptop, this page will contain the answer for you.

The key is to use the Function Key (Fn) and press F4, which will toggle the display:

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Display-and-Video/How-do-I-connect-my-laptop-to-an-external-monitor/td-p/519487